# Change DIV children to display none

Tags: javascript, styles, display

HTML

```
    <div id="divID">
      <label></label>
      <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
```

JavaScript

```
function invisible(){
 let div = document.getElementById("divID");
 let children = div.childNodes;
   for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
      children[i].style.display = "none";
   }
 }
```

After calling the function nothing happens. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set `divID` to your `div` tag.

```
    <div id="divID">
      <label></label>
      <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
```

And then you have to use `div.children` in `invisible` function.

```js
function invisible(){
 let div = document.getElementById("divID");
 let children = div.children;
   for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
      children[i].style.display = "none";
   }
 }
```

```html
   <input type="button" onClick=" invisible()" value="Remove" />
   <div id="divID">
      <label></label>
      <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
```

Comment: My div has an ID. I forgot to add it to the example.  That was not the problem.  I edited the example.

Comment: Ok the other things is `div.children`. Please run my code and see the result. That works well

Comment: div.children doesn't work. I used div.childNodes following the MDN example.

Comment: @cat15ets I edit my code to better understand. I add `remove button`. Please run the code and press the `remove button`

Comment: Your code is good! It Works! It seems that my problem is more complex! I use bootstrap and this piece of html is inside some form element that has it's own style.display = "block". I have to do some tests :)

Comment: OK, all works! I also had a typo. The main problem was childNodes. I replaced childNodes with children, corrected a typo and all works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can make the function more reusable by accepting the element whose children are to be hidden as the first argument. It currently only works for the element with id of `"divID"`.

```js
function invisible(parent){
 for(const child of parent.children) child.style.display = 'none';
}
invisible(document.querySelector('div'))
```

```html
 <div>
   <label>Label</label>
   <textarea>Textarea</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes the problem was with childNodes. node.children works, node.childNodes doesn't. I accepted the answer above because it was the first one, but this also works and it looks good

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be your use of [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) instead of [`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children) as other answers have pointed out.

This answer attempts to give some more context on what is happening in addition to the other answers.

```
let div = document.getElementById("divID");

console.log(div.childNodes)
// Returns something like
NodeList(5) [text, label, text, textarea, text]

console.log(div.children)
// Returns something like
HTMLCollection(2) [label, textarea]
```

So `childNodes` returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) and `children` returns an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).

[The definition `children` on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children) explains the difference between `children` and `childNodes`:

> Element.children includes only element nodes. To get all child nodes, including non-element nodes like text and comment nodes, use Node.childNodes.

The problem is that these `text` nodes don't have a `style` property. So it returns `undefined`. Trying to access the `display` property on `style` then causes a `TypeError`. Since the first element is a `text` element the loop fails immediately and the `label` and `textarea` are never hidden.

Answer (score 0):

use `children` instead of `childNodes`:

```js
function invisible(){
 let div = document.getElementById("divID");
 let children = div.children; //<== children instead of childNodes
   for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
      children[i].style.display = "none";
   }
 }
 //just to test after 1.5 sec all children of divID will be removed(display=none)
setTimeout(invisible, 1500)
```

```html
<div id='divID'>
  <label>test1</label>
  <textarea>test2</textarea>
</div>
```